# Datanode one of the disk volume failure

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager

One of the disk from my hadoop cluster datanode has become read only. I am not sure what caused this problem. 
Will removing this volume from the datanode cause data lose ?? 
How to handle this if i am going to face data lose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hadoop cluster was having a replication factor of more than 1 (by default it is 3 for a multi-node cluster), your data must have been replicated on multiple datanodes. You can check your replication factor value (dfs.replication) in hdfs-site.xml.

So now if you remove this read-only datanode from your cluster and you have a replication factor of more than 1, then you will not face any data loss. Because your cluster will have a corresponding replica on other datanode. To balance the replicas, under-replicated blocks will be handled by hdfs automatically and subsequently hdfs will be stable.